# Reference Errors thrown in included file... unless calling file includes slow code

Tags: javascript

A funny thing happened to me while I was cleaning up some old JavaScript code this week. When I took out some slow code, the page started throwing Reference Errors on code in a file that was included via an Ajax call.

Below is (greatly simplified) example of the issue. The first file will work without error when requested directly. But when called via Ajax, the document-ready event has already occurred, so the code within executes immediately. Chrome throws an error such as: "VM1414:2 Uncaught ReferenceError: they_log is not defined"

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() { 
        they_log("Be alerted");
    });
</script>
<!-- Two separate script tags prevent hoisting -->
<script>
function they_log($string) {

    console.log($string);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

However, if the comment "alert" line below is uncommented, the Reference Errors are not thrown in Chrome or Firefox (although they still occur in Safari - unless you let the modal dialog hang open for several seconds).

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Prototype of reference error issue</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="place" />

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.2/jquery.js"></script>

    <script>
        $.get( "http://localhost/path/to/first/file.html", function( data ) {
          $("#place").html(data);
        });
        //alert("I get rid of the reference error");
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My question is, how does the alert message (or similar slow code in the including file) prevent the reference errors from occuring?

I'm particularly interested if whatever is happening to let the code execute without error can be counted on to work consistently (in Chrome and Firefox, at least) or if there is something like a race condition going on where it may fail intermittently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I observe is your `alert` run before document ready, and it **prevents document ready** until the alert dialog is closed. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/24pg3yzk/

While the alert dialog is displayed, the Ajax request and its done handler `$("#place").html(data);` **may** have finished. So yes, it's race condition.

Is it standard or consistent behavior? I don't know. I think it makes sense since alert "Dialog boxes are modal windows - they prevent the user from accessing the rest of the program's interface until the dialog box is closed" ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert)), but nothing to affirm it from the jQuery [doc](https://api.jquery.com/ready/).

Comment: Thanks for that fiddle. Based on your answer I did some more testing, and yes it's definitely a race. If you click OK fast enough, the error will still appear in Chrome (though I could get it to happen in FF). And if you give Safari enough time (5-10 seconds) before clicking through the alert box, you can get the error not to appear.